# How to enforce the default timeout interval in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, protractor, timeout

I am trying to set a timeout for my automation script using protactor and jasmine. I have set the default jasmine timeout to 5 seconds.
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 5000,
 }
When I try to test the 5 second timeout, the script runs for 20 seconds in total, even after the spec has timed out. 
So basically it keeps executing until it times out 4 times.

This is my terminal -

A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.

A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.

A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.

A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.

Failures:
1) Timeout issue debugger Set timeout and see if it exceeds

Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:427:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:289:5)
        at listOnTimeout (timers.js:252:5)
        at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:212:10)

Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:427:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:289:5)
        at listOnTimeout (timers.js:252:5)
        at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:212:10)

Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:427:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:289:5)
        at listOnTimeout (timers.js:252:5)
        at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:212:10)

Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:427:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:289:5)
        at listOnTimeout (timers.js:252:5)
        at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:212:10)

This is how I am testing it -

```
describe('Timeout issue debugger', () => {
  afterEach(done => {
    helper.reportTestRails().then(function() {
      done();
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    helper.updateResults();
  });

  it('Set timeout and see if it exceeds and works properly', async () => {
    browser.sleep(30000);
  });
)};
```

I will appreciate any suggestions or solutions.

Comment: You could add timeout in your script . describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {
   browser.driver.manage().timeouts(250000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to not mix protractor control flow and async/await together. This cases horrible bugs like yours. Also Control flow is deprecated and already removed from v6.x

I suggest:
1) Set `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` in your protactor config file
2) Use await everywhere: Prepend all async commands with await:

```
describe('Timeout issue debugger', function () {
  afterEach(async function () {
    await helper.reportTestRails();
    await helper.updateResults();
  });

  it('Set timeout and see if it exceeds and works properly', async function () {
    await browser.sleep(10000);
  });
)};
```

http://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await

Comment: It worked! I set the ```SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false``` and it worked fine.
Thanks you Xotabu4.